# Why is google still indexing HTTP when I used React-Helmet and set canonical link to HTTPS?

Tags: reactjs, http, npm, react-helmet, google-search-platform

Google indexed **HTTP** URL for my site, but I want it to index **HTTPS**.

I searched for a solution and found **React-Helmet**.

After I implemented React-Helmet, adding HTTPS URL as the canonical link. I asked Google to re-crawl. Google results updated to include the React-Helmet meta description (see below):

> Google Search 
>   Web Results:
>
> **Cratic** | **The Culture Builder**
>
> *cratic.ai*
>
> Cratic is the #1 culture-building product in the market: a portal into the social dynamics of your organization. This toolkit
>   puts the power of Culture AI at your ...

This means I know that React-Helmet is working.

However, Google did not update the link. Google is still indexed to the HTTP link, not HTTPS. This means anytime someone finds my site from Google, they are sent to the non-secure site, even though I have added HTTPS url as the canonical link (see below):

```
      <Helmet>
        <title>Cratic | The Culture Builder</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Cratic is the #1 culture-building product in the market: a portal into the social dynamics of your organization. This toolkit puts the power of Culture AI at your fingertips." />
        <meta name="keywords" content="culture,change,management,ai,future-of-work,workplace,leading,dynamics" />
        <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.cratic.ai" />
      </Helmet>
```

My understanding was that the link: **rel="canonical" href="https://www.cratic.ai"** will notify Google to index to the HTTPS url. But this doesn't seem to be the case.

Can you help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Bing and Yahoo are also indexing HTTP, which is making me think it may be a DNS rerouting issue. Still investigating, but I will leave this post up until I resolve...